# Sonarqube 4.2 & PHP

Tags: php, sonarqube

since I updated to sonar 4.2 and the PHP plugin to 2.1 there is no way to use results or execute external tools like phpcs and phpmd.

We used phpcs quite extensively before - I wanted to know is there any way to get our phpcs rules back in Sonar as else the php analysis run is not much use to us. I have not found a way to define my own new rules, just found those few that come with the plugin (for comparison we had 580 rules before, and now have 28).

Hope someone can help us ;)

Thanks,

Susanne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We hope to eventually include the ability to write custom rules in Java: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPHP-270
In the meantime, please join the user list and tell us what rules you'd like to see re-implemented.